# SIGUSR1 terminates the process although i have blocked it

Tags: c, linux

i have a program which creates 2 child processes, so, child 1 sends SIGINT to child 2, child 2 handles SIGINT(the handler of SIGINT blocks SIGUSR1), after SIGINT, child 1 sends SIGUSR1 to child 2.
I don't know why SIGUSR1 terminates child 2. SIGUSR1 gets blocked when SIGINT is sent.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sigset_t base_mask, waiting_mask;

void handler(int signum)
{
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
  sigemptyset (&base_mask);
  sigaddset (&base_mask, SIGUSR1);
  /* Block user interrupts while doing other processing. */
  if(sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &base_mask, NULL) != 0)
    printf("cannot block\n");
  else
    printf("SIGUSR1 blocked\n");
  if(sigismember(&base_mask, SIGUSR1))
    printf("sigusr1 in mask\n");
}

int main()
{
 if(fork())
  {
    if(fork())
    {
      printf("parent out\n");
    }
    else//child 2
    {
      printf("i am sib 2 with pid = %d\n", getpid());
      signal(SIGINT, handler);
      pause();
      printf("before sleep\n");
      sleep(10);
      printf("after sleep\n");
      /* After a while, check to see whether any signals are pending. */
      sigpending (&waiting_mask);
      if (sigismember (&waiting_mask, SIGUSR1))
        printf("/* SIGUSR1 pending. */\n");
      sleep(2);
      printf("2 out\n");
    }
  }
  else//child 1
 {
    printf("i am sib 1 with pid = %d\n", getpid());
    sleep(2);
    printf("SIGINT to %d\n", getpid() + 1);
    if(kill(getpid() + 1, SIGINT))
      printf("Signal cannot be sent\n");
    sleep(4);
    if(kill(getpid() + 1, SIGUSR1))
      printf("Signal 2 cannot be sent\n");
    else
      printf("SIGUSR1 sent to %d\n", getpid() + 1);
    sleep(4);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
parent out,
i am sib 1 with pid = 2525,
i am sib 2 with pid = 2526,
SIGINT to 2526,
SIGUSR1 blocked,
sigusr1 in mask,
before sleep,
SIGUSR1 sent to 2526
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: You block the signal here in the signal handler:

```
void handler(int signum) {
  ...
  if(sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &base_mask, NULL) != 0)
    printf("cannot block\n");
  else
    printf("SIGUSR1 blocked\n");
  if(sigismember(&base_mask, SIGUSR1))
    printf("sigusr1 in mask\n");
}
```

But after *returning* from the signal handler, the blocked signals mask is *restored* to the value it had on entry of the handler! So, calling `sigprocmask()` has only effect on the blocked signals during the current handler invocation. You have to call it outside the signal handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!, i was struggling with this for almost 2 days! I do not know why my teacher gave me such a problem, it says "SIGUSR1 gets blocked in the handler of SIGINT"

Comment: Could you please tell me how/where you found out that, that was the problem? because i have not found anywhere that _sigprocmask()_ acts like this in documentations or man page

Comment: It is not `sigprocmask()`, but the restorer of the signal handler (`rt_sigreturn()`), which is called implicitly when returnign from a signal handler. I have found this reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signals-in-Handler.html . Citation: `When the handler returns, the set of blocked signals is restored to the value it had before the handler ran. So using sigprocmask inside the handler only affects what signals can arrive during the execution of the handler itself, not what signals can arrive once the handler returns.`